# Is it better to hide/show an element or append it?

Tags: jquery

Which one is the preferred method and why?

**Method 1:**

```
<p>When I'm clicked, add an image under me.</p>
<img src="/path/to/image.gif" />

$('p').hide(); // OR css display:none
$('p').click(function() {
    $('img').show();
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
<p>When I'm clicked, add an image under me.</p>

$('p').click(function() {
    $('<img src="/path/to/image.gif" />').appendTo('p');
});
```

Comment: Whether one method or the other is preferred depends completely on the situation.

Comment: really depends on how you are using it. if it only triggers once, id say method 2.. if you are toggling hide & show, then use method 1

Comment: They both cause only one redraw, so performance wise the difference should be negligible. Which way would be more maintainable and/or easier to read? It is more common to just hide/show the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In this precise case*, the first solution seems better as it enables the browser to start loading the image long before the user clicks.

When you don't have so great behavior differences, I'd suggest to keep the solution enabling you to have the cleanest and simplest code. And that will depend on much more code that what you can show us.

Even there, it might be possible that the second solution is better if it's more coherent with a framework or your image is almost ensured to be in cache for other reasons.